# Include path error via cron job script

Tags: php, cron, include

I keep getting an include error from my cron job output.

The output I get is:

```
    ?>): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/yeelloe/cron.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '<?php

//PLEASE do NOT move me around. I get cranky when I get moved around

//get the wp-load in for the wordpress functions

$parse_uri = explode( '/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );

require_once( $parse_uri[0] . '/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-load.php' );

//now try calling template function

CheckFunction();

?>' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php:/opt/bitnami/frameworks/smarty/libs') in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/yeelloe/cron.php on line 5
```

I've tried changing the include path to the file I'm trying to include but this still gives me an error. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You will not get `$_SERVER` if you run cron with php command as it will not generate http request.

Comment: what should I replace it with?

Comment: use `wget URL` instead of `php pathtoscrit`

Comment: can anyone help me out here?